# Multiple moderators in Outlook meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, meetings

We have the problem that we want to make meeting requests that multiple people can edit and get acceptance or cancellation answers.

Is that possible somehow?

Right now only one person can edit the request and see who accepted.

Comment: Shared mailbox for sending meeting invites is one solution. Not ideal one, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a predefined group of people (let's say project team or (small) HR), you can create shared mailbox to Exchange and use that to send calendar invites. That way invite replies goes to same place, and everyone with access to mailbox can edit calendar entries too.